# Get details in console instead of "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, object, console.log

I have maybe a real simple problem, but I need to know how to do this.
My ambitions:

```js
var test_obj = {     
  'test' : 't',
  'test2' : 't2'
}
/*
when i log a object it often gives me somthing like this:
 [object Object]
 
but if i want to take a look into the object, i want to see (for test_obj):
{ 'test' : 't', 'test2' : 't2' }
  
*/
```

So how can I log an object that it shows me what the content ?

Comment: How you are logging it?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(test_obj)`

Comment: If you're in Chrome, you know you can expand the `object Object` by clicking on it on the console, right?

Comment: @Wainage getting the error: Type Error: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: When I run `console.log(test_obj);`, I get the details of the object (in Chrome): `Object {test: "t", test2: "t2"}`

Comment: Yup. That will happen for large objects that have circular references. What are you trying to log? It's definitely not your test_obj

Comment: @Jason yes in chrome you can also click on the object and see what's in it, but i'm not in chrome

Comment: Try this : var keys = Object.keys(test_obj);
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
     {
            JSON.stringify(keys[i]);}

Comment: @Wainage a connection object returned from WebSocket.onopen

Comment: @javascript.beginner. yeah. that's a big object with many circular references. What do you need out of the object? Or are you `just looking`?

Comment: It occurs when you concatenate string + object: `console.log('' + test_obj);`, try instead `console.log(test_obj);` or using `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @Wainage wanted to see what's in it, so nothing special...and thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: Grab WebStorm and check out the objects in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your object into string representation. Use JSON Stringify on the object and then you can display it.  Try this code

`JSON.stringify(test_obj)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the object index: 
You can try this:

```
var keys = Object.keys(test_obj);
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
        {
            JSON.stringify(keys[i]);
}
```

Comment: Or use `for...in`?

Comment: Yep it can be used too instead of regular "for"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify` with proper parameter for formated output.

```js
var test_obj = {     
   'test' : 't',
   'test2' : 't2'
};

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(test_obj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```